# Bootstrap card [text-overflow: ellipsis] after a few lines of text

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I create a web application using the Bootstrap library. I use card classes. What I want to achieve is truncate too long text, as in the picture below:

[image: bootstrap card1]

Unfortunately, the only thing I manage to achieve is this result:

[image: bootstrap card2]

I would like the text to wrap over several lines, not immediately after the first.

My `html` code:

```
 <div class="card mb-3">
              <div class="row no-gutters">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                  <img src="https://wallpaperstock.net/eclipse_wallpapers_26124_1280x720.jpg" class="card-img" alt="...">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-8">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
                    <p class="card-text description-text">This is a wider card with supporting text below as a natural lead-in to additional content. This content is a little bit longer.</p>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

My `css` code:

```
.card-img {
  color: #fff;
  height: 10rem;
  object-fit:cover;
}

.description-text {
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

What can I add or change to make the text go to the end of the card and then truncated?

Comment: delete white-space: nowrap;

Comment: Now the text doesn't wrap, it just expands the card.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some tricks to achieve this:
https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/#the-hide-overflow-place-ellipsis-pure-css-way